# Why Hydrogen bomb is called "Thermonuclear Bomb"?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, hydrogen, fusion, explosions

Why do we call Hydrogen bomb as "[Thermonuclear Bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermonuclear_weapon)" ?

Comment: I think that the wikipedia article explains that pretty good

Comment: Mainly to distinguish it from an "atom bomb", which is a fission-based nuclear weapon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its called "thermonuclear" because its energy producing nuclear fusion reaction is started by the extremely high temperatures of a nuclear fission bomb.

Comment: Nuclear fission isn't the only way to get a thermonuclear reaction started; it's just the easiest in a bomb. A controlled thermonuclear reaction would be stated a different way.